# Subprogram or cursor 'USER' reference is out of scope

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to define a trigger which fires before any insert in Cliente table but I'm absolutely unable to do so. Here it is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER updateSaldoCuenta
BEFORE INSERT ON Cliente
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'TRY');
END;
/
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
BEFORE INSERT ON Cliente
                 *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06552: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
ORA-06553: PLS-225: subprogram or cursor 'USER' reference is out of scope
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: are you sure you have a table `Cliente` in your current schema? Or it's a name of an object of another type such as a `stored procedure`, `function`, `type` ..etc. ?

Comment: Yes, it's a table in my current schema

Comment: Is that your complete Trigger code which is failing? Do you have any references to "USER" somewhere which you're not showing?

Comment: This works fine in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7581c9cd7502e941a46bcbeedde26fbd)... I suspect that the error you are getting comes from some other part of your code.

Comment: @KaushikNayak USER is the user I log in to the system with

Comment: @GMB Question edited so my current schema is visible

Answer (score 0):

Just creating a new user did the trick! I suppose something went wrong with the other